# Wrong time after wake up from suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend, time

Every time my system wakes up from suspend it shows the wrong time, even though it is set to get the network time. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be your builtin CMOS does not count time during Ubuntu suspend. It is also interesting, what time is in bios after some time your laptop is being powered off.

To find out what happened it is desirable to know what your system says about it.

For example, you could use the next command to find out what is going on when you sleep/resume your system:

```
$ sudo journalctl -f | grep sync
бер 09 17:58:41 lenovo kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.190 seconds
бер 09 17:59:43 lenovo kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.143 seconds
```

To see more detailed output, you could hit in the terminal:

```
$ sudo journalctl -f
```

Then close the laptop's lid for some time and then open it.

After that you could examine what is going on on the background and show it here.

To workaround your issue, new systemd service could be created which will synchronize date forcefully by restarting your time service just after suspend, as it described here: https://superuser.com/a/1529040/1032713

Comment: Thank. I actually just get one output which is:
mar 11 13:59:51 Precision-5530 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.007 seconds